# UILabel subclass - text cut off in bottom despite label being correct height

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a problem with UILabel subclass cutting off text in the bottom. Label is of proper height to fit the text, there is some space left in the bottom, but the text is still being cut off.

[image: The label]

The red stripes are border added to label's layer.

I subclass the label to add edge insets.

```
override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    var size = super.sizeThatFits(size)
    size.width += insets.left + insets.right
    size.height += insets.top + insets.bottom
    return size
}

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}
```

However, in this particular case the insets are zero.

Comment: try to increase UILabel height because the height of label is less than the font size or decrease font size.

Comment: As you can see, the text height is lower than label's height. Also, if I use regular label instead of this subclass, the text is not cut off.

Comment: @mag_zbc  which custom font are you using.

Comment: What worked for me was allowing the containing view to become taller, as in `Height >=`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out the problem was with

```
self.lineBreakMode = .ByClipping
```

changing it to

```
self.lineBreakMode = .ByCharWrapping
```

Solved the problem

Answer (score 12):

My problem was that the label's (vertical) content compression resistance priority was not high enough; setting it to required (1000) fixed it.

*It looks like the other non-OP answers may be some sort of workaround for this same underlying issue.*

Answer (score 12):

I was facing the same issue with *Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold* font. Changing label's **Baseline** property from ***Align Baselines*** to ***Align Centers*** did the trick for me. You can change this easily in storyboard by selecting your label.

Comment: Same here. Using *Helvetica Neue Condensed Bold* for a text label. Setting the property helped.

Comment: If it didn't work, try ".none". I submit an answer explaining this slight different approach and why ".alignCenters" solution should work only sometimes.

Answer (score 8):

## TL'DR

Probably the property you are looking for is *UILabel*'s `baselineAdjustment`.

It is needed because of an old UILabel's known bug. Try it:

```swift
label.baselineAdjustment = .none
```

Also it could be changed through *interface builder*. This property could be found under *UILabel's Attributes inspector* with the name *"Baseline"*.

[image: Baseline property on Interface Builder]

---

## Explanation

#### It's a bug

There is some discussions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44410932/6704959) about a bug on UILabel's text bounding box. What we observe here in our case is some version of this bug. It looks like the **bounding box grows in height when we shrink the text** through AutoShrink `.minimumFontScale` or `.minimumFontSize`.

As a consequence, the bounding box grows bigger than the line height and the visible portion of UILabel's height. That said, with  `baselineAdjustment` property set to it's default state, `.alignBaselines`, text aligns to the cropped bottom and we could observe line clipping.

Understanding this behaviour is crucial to explain why set `.alignCenters` solve some problems but not others. Just center text on the bigger bounding box could still clip it.

---

## Solution

So the best approach is to set

```swift
label.baselineAdjustment = .none
```

The documentation for the `.none` case said:

> Adjust text relative to the top-left corner of the bounding box. This
>   is the default adjustment.

Since bonding box origin matches the label's frame, it should fix any problem for a one-lined label with `AutoShrink` enabled.

Also it could be changed through *interface builder*. This property could be found under *UILabel's Attributes inspector* with the name *"Baseline"*.

---

## Documentation

You could read more here about *UILabel's* `baselineAdjustment`on official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620524-baselineadjustment).

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but doesn't work on my case. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

Happened for me when providing topAnchor and centerYAnchor for label at the same time.
Leaving just one anchor fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this too, but wanted to avoid adding a height constraint. I'd already created a `UILabel` subclass that allowed me to add content insets (but for the purpose of setting `tableHeaderView` straight to a label without having to contain it in another view). Using the class I could set the bottom inset to solve the issue with the font clipping.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class InsetLabel: UILabel {

    @IBInspectable var topInset: CGFloat = 16
    @IBInspectable var bottomInset: CGFloat = 16
    @IBInspectable var leftInset: CGFloat = 16
    @IBInspectable var rightInset: CGFloat = 16
    var insets: UIEdgeInsets {
        get {
            return UIEdgeInsets(
                top: topInset,
                left: leftInset,
                bottom: bottomInset,
                right: rightInset
            )
        }
    }

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: insets))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return addInsetsTo(size: super.intrinsicContentSize)
    }

    override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return addInsetsTo(size: super.sizeThatFits(size))
    }

    func addInsetsTo(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(
            width: size.width + leftInset + rightInset,
            height: size.height + topInset + bottomInset
        )
    }

}
```

This could be simplified just for the font clipping to:

```
import UIKit

class FontFittingLabel: UILabel {

    var inset: CGFloat = 16 // Adjust this

    override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawText(in: rect.inset(by: UIEdgeInsets(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            bottom: inset,
            right: 0
        )))
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = super.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height + inset
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: I suspect some fonts to have a configuration problem which leads to this bug. Very nice solution to get around it.

Comment: This is not working for very long text. Last 2 words are getting cut always.

Comment: UILabel seems to cut off no matter what anyone tries, it's maddening.  The solution is to just shift to a textView-- wish I had done that a long time ago because UILabel is a complete and utter Apple nightmare wrapped in a tornado.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers didn't help me, but what did was constraining the height of the label to whatever height it needed, like so:

```
let unconstrainedSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: label.sizeThatFits(unconstrainedSize).height).isActive = true
```

Also, `sizeThatFits(_:)` will return a `0 by 0` size if your label's `text` field is `nil` or equal to `""`

Answer (score 1):

I had a vertical `UIStackView` with a `UILabel` at the bottom. This `UILabel` was cutting off the letters that go below the baseline (`q`, `g`, `y`, etc), but only when nested inside a horizontal `UIStackView`. The fix was to add the `.lastBaseline` alignment modifier to the outer stack view.

```swift
    lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            aVerticalStackWithUILabelAtBottom, // <-- bottom UILabel was cutoff
            UIView(),
            someOtherView 
        ])
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.spacing = Spacing.one
        stackView.alignment = .lastBaseline // <-- BOOM fixed it
        stackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return stackView
    }()
```