# iOS UILabel bounding rectangle not sized correctly

Tags: ios, autolayout, uilabel

I have a UILabel (as highlighted in yellow), which has the following conditions applied to it.

- Label has variable text length
- Font set to 40
- Minimum font-size set to 20
- Number of lines set to 3

Although this looks like a duplicated question I believe it is not. The issue I am having is that when the text exceeds the available 3 line length after being sized-down to 20 points, the UILabel's bounding box is sized incorrectly (i.e. note the extraneous spacing above and below the text).

The end result should be a UILabel without any spacing. Is there are solution to this, while keeping the number of lines set to 3?

[image: UILabel with text]

Comment: You are using autolayout?, your constraints can be the problem?

Comment: can your constraints setup for your UILabel?

Comment: @ Reinier Melian No, it's not a constraint issue. I stripped back the code into a very simple example and have tried different combinations of constraints to make sure the issue wasn't coming from there. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I will try by myself with an example and see what happens

Comment: When you set a Font Size of 40, and Minimum Font Size of 20, that means as you change the frame of your label, the font will automatically change size so the text fits. If you are changing the Font Size, it will *not* affect the frame of the `UILabel`

Comment: @ DonMag Indeed, this may be what is happening, but in my opinion the frame size _should_ match the resized text... otherwise what would be the point of being able to resize the font in the first place? If the number of lines is set to 0 then the frame expands to fit the content, and conversely, it should contract when the point size is reduced. I'll read the apple docs to see if that can clarify this point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug. If you increase your base font size, you will see the space increase. Also, if you inspect the layout at runtime, you will see the content size to be calculated as too big.

My guess is, UILabel takes your original font size (40) to calculate the content size for 3 lines of text and does not take into account that the font size has already been decreased before truncation.

I fiddled with content hugging/compression priorities but could not make it work either.

The only workaround I found was to manually set the font size down to 20. That will get you the frame you want.

Comment: Thanks Andi. That was also my assumption, but I wondered whether there was an autolayout expert who had previously resolved this issue. I suspect the combination of requirements are simply not achievable, and that I will have to resort to losing either the minimum font-size or set the lines to 0.